# Re-attaching Marionette.View and events handling

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views, backbone-events

Lets say, that I’ve got simple app, which is created with Backbone.Marionette.
For sake of simplicity, assume that I’ve got „Show” view for some model (it doesn’t matter here what it is), where I can click „Add new”, which shows me „new” view in „modal” window.

I’m displaying there simple form, which (after validation) is sent to my API. During that, I’m displaying other view (which displays sth. like „Saving, please wait…”).

In case of success, I’m closing this modal window, and everything is OK.

However (that is the tricky part): I would like to handle situations, when from some reason model was not saved (API temporary downtime, connection issue, race condition etc.), and display same view another time (I thought that it should be easy) – however, when I’m doing this, events aren’t handled anymore (ie: `submitForm` action is not executed second time :( )

Here is my my proof of concept for this:

```
class MyApp.SampleView extends Marionette.View
  events:
    "submit form": "submitForm"

   submitForm: (event) ->
     event.preventDefault()

     data = $(event.currentTarget).serializeObject()

     model = SampleModel.new(data)

     if model.isValid()
       MyApp.popupRegion.show(SavingPopup)
       savePromise = model.save()

       savePromise.success =>
         @close()
         @displayNotification("Model has been added")
       savePromise.error =>
         @displayNotification("Something went wrong, please try again")
         MyApp.popupRegion.show(this) # displays correct view
                                      # but does not handle events :(
```

## TL;DR version:

How to re–append view to region in such way that my events still will be handled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before a region `show()`'s a view it calls `close()` on the currently displayed view. `close()` acts as the view's destructor, unbinding all events, rendering it useless and allowing the garbage collector to dispose of it.

When you execute `MyApp.popupRegion.show(SavingPopup)`, `this` is `close()`'d. You will need to create a new instance of the view in `savePromise.error`, or find some other way to signal your application that the view needs to be recreated.

Something like this should work:

```
savePromise.error =>
     @displayNotification("Something went wrong, please try again")
     MyApp.popupRegion.show(new MyApp.SampleView)
```